# Find unused resources using SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

Is there any good way to find unused resources on subscription using python SDK?

I found info about changed time using ResourceManagementClient but I dont think it is the best source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code   :

```
import os

from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

subscription_id = os.environ.get(
    'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID',
    '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111') # your Azure Subscription Id

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
    secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
)
client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    print_item(item)
```

please refer these following documents for more information.
[Manage Azure resources and resource groups with Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups/manage-azure-resources-and-resource-groups-with-python/#list-resources),
[Use the Azure libraries to list resource groups and resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-list-resource-groups),
[Finding Unused Resources Impacting Azure Costs](https://www.sqlshack.com/finding-unused-resources-impacting-azure-costs/)